# flv from vlc to ffmpeg live video error when no sound temporarily

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, flv, live, vlc

When we get live stream from vlc to ffmpeg , wherever there is sometimes 5-6 second no sound part of video  , then ffmpeg is dead with this log

flv @ 0x8b426d0]illegal ac vlc code at 4x6

[flv @ 0x8b426d0]Error at MB: 142

[flv @ 0x8b426d0]concealing 257 DC, 257 AC, 257 MV errors

[mpegts @ 0x8b44e50]dts < pcr, TS is invalid

Is there anyway to avoid this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

dvch,
This error occurs when you have corrupted bits in your video capture. With RTP or live streams, this happens a lot since UDP will drop packets. FFMPEG tries hard to recover these areas, but there will be some loss depending on format.

Try grabbing a live stream that is encoded in raw h263, one in raw h263+, and one in raw h264, and see what works better for you. VLC should do a good job of the packetization, so it may be the decoder within FFMPEG that is causing the problem. You could try GStreamer,

My working pipeline:

Sender: 
gst-launch-0.10 -v filesrc location=June/akiyo_qcif.264 ! h264parse ! 
video/x-h264 ! rtph264pay pt=96 config-interval=5 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 
port=42050 sync=false

Receiver: 
gst-launch-0.10 udpsrc port=42050 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, 
clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96, 
ssrc=(guint)4091714163, clock-base=(guint)4007889851, seqnum-base=(guint)31909" 
! rtph264depay ! filesink location=June/test6.264

via Farah at
[Gstreamer-devel Post about Streaming RTP and h264](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Using-gstreamer-to-transmit-H264-file-over-RTP-td2236364.html)

I hope this helps, I have had this same error to, using h263-1998 over RTP/AVP even on a local network, h263 has no hiccups, and h264 has no hiccups, but there is something going on with FFMPEG and h263p format.

Here are the same errors I was getting to with FFMPEG.

[h263 @ 0x101015a00] illegal ac vlc code at 12x15
[h263 @ 0x101015a00] Error at MB: 357
[h263 @ 0x101015a00] concealing 44 DC, 44 AC, 44 MV errors

Cheers,
Scott Haines

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 -b:v 64k <your out put method>
```

use it before declaring your out put.